# Tableview settings going away when the cell is scrolled away

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

**Background**:
I have a tableview with a custom cell with 2 vote buttons that pulls JSON data from the server, if it says the user isn't allowed to vote, then it loads the cell with the buttons disabled and colored gray instead of the default blue.

**Problem**:
When someone clicks a button on the cell to vote, it disables/grays the buttons for the cell, but when I scroll past the cell and scroll back, it just defaults back to enabled blue buttons until I pull to refresh from the table and it gets the server data again.

**What I think is the solution**:
I should be modifying the local array that stores whether the user can vote or not (disableArray) at the indexPath of the button that was clicked, but I don't know how.

**So how can I access and modify the** `disableArray` **from the vote functions inside my custom tableViewCell subclass?**

here is the code for my custom tableViewCell:

```
 import UIKit

    class MainTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

        @IBOutlet weak var totalvoteLabel: UILabel!
        @IBOutlet weak var upButton: UIButton!
        @IBOutlet weak var downButton: UIButton!

        var number: Int?{
            return Int(totalvoteLabel.text!)
        }

        override func awakeFromNib() {
            super.awakeFromNib()
        }


        @IBAction func downvote(sender: AnyObject) {
            totalvoteLabel.text = String(number! - 1)
            upButton.userInteractionEnabled = false
            downButton.userInteractionEnabled = false
            upButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "upArrowGray.png"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
            downButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "downArrowGray.png"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
            totalvoteLabel.textColor =  UIColor(red: 188/255, green: 183/255, blue: 174/255, alpha: 1.0)

        }
        @IBAction func upvote(sender: AnyObject) {
            totalvoteLabel.text = String(number! + 1)
            upButton.userInteractionEnabled = false
            downButton.userInteractionEnabled = false
            upButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "upArrowGray.png"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
            downButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "downArrowGray.png"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
            totalvoteLabel.textColor =  UIColor(red: 188/255, green: 183/255, blue: 174/255, alpha: 1.0)      
        }
    }
```

and the code for my tableView:

```
   func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
            return 1
        }
        func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
                           return postArray.count
            }

        func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

            let cell : MainTableViewCell! = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("MainTableViewCell") as! MainTableViewCell

            cell.totalvoteLabel.text = voteArray[indexPath.row]
            cell.ID = idArray[indexPath.row]

            if(disableArray[indexPath.row] == "1"){
                cell.upButton.userInteractionEnabled = false
                cell.downButton.userInteractionEnabled = false
                cell.upButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "upArrowGray.png"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
                cell.downButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "downArrowGray.png"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
                cell.totalvoteLabel.textColor =  UIColor(red: 188/255, green: 183/255, blue: 174/255, alpha: 1.0)
                cell.disable = true
            }else{
                cell.upButton.userInteractionEnabled = true
                cell.downButton.userInteractionEnabled = true
                cell.upButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "upArrow.png"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
                cell.downButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "downArrow.png"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
                cell.totalvoteLabel.textColor =  UIColor(red: 43/255, green: 192/255, blue: 228/255, alpha: 1.0)
            }

            return cell as MainTableViewCell
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you should update your `disableArray` each time one of the buttons are clicked. You can achieve that with delegation.

1. Create a protocol that takes an `NSIndexPath`
2. Create two variables inside `MainTableViewCell` for indexPath and delegate
3. Call the delegate and pass the indexPath from `upVote` and `downVote` methods.

Now the code for `MainTableViewCell` should look like this:

```
import UIKit

//**** The Protocol ****
protocol MyCellProtocol {
    func updateDisableArray (indexPath: NSIndexPath)
}

class MainTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var totalvoteLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var upButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var downButton: UIButton!

    var number: Int?{
        return Int(totalvoteLabel.text!)
    }

    //**** Variable to store the indexPath ****
    var indexPath: NSIndexPath!

    //**** Variable for the delegate ****
    var cellDelegate: MyCellProtocol?

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }


    @IBAction func downvote(sender: AnyObject) {
        totalvoteLabel.text = String(number! - 1)
        upButton.userInteractionEnabled = false
        downButton.userInteractionEnabled = false
        upButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "upArrowGray.png"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        downButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "downArrowGray.png"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        totalvoteLabel.textColor =  UIColor(red: 188/255, green: 183/255, blue: 174/255, alpha: 1.0)

        //****  Call the delegate method with the indexPath ****
        self.cellDelegate?.updateDisableArray(indexPath)

    }
    @IBAction func upvote(sender: AnyObject) {
        totalvoteLabel.text = String(number! + 1)
        upButton.userInteractionEnabled = false
        downButton.userInteractionEnabled = false
        upButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "upArrowGray.png"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        downButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "downArrowGray.png"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        totalvoteLabel.textColor =  UIColor(red: 188/255, green: 183/255, blue: 174/255, alpha: 1.0)

        //****  Call the delegate method with the indexPath ****
        self.cellDelegate?.updateDisableArray(indexPath)      
    }
}
```

4. In the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method of your table view configure the `cellDelegate` and `indexPath` properties of the Cell, like this:

   ```
   func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

       let cell : MainTableViewCell! = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("MainTableViewCell") as! MainTableViewCell

       //**** Set self to be the cellDelegate ****
       cell.cellDelegate = self

       //**** Set the indexPath property of the cell ****
       cell.indexPath = indexPath

       cell.totalvoteLabel.text = voteArray[indexPath.row]
   ```
5. Make the ViewController that contains the tableView and your disableArray confirm to `MyCellProtocol` :

   ```
   class ViewControllerOfYourTableView: UIViewController, MyCellProtocol {
   ```
6. Implement `MyCellProtocol` in the view controller. you can put this right after your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method:

   ```
   func updateDisableArray (indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
       //**** update the array at the indexPath of the clicked button ****
       self.disableArray[indexPath.row] = "1"
   }
   ```